# Drawing shape within a charts that would override the current graph

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js, charts, recharts

Let's say you have a developed a chart in reactJS in which you display a graph, a simple line composed of points you plotted based on time(abscissa) and degree (ordinate).

You have a toolbox you can pick up from, so that you can draw a shape within the chart, that would override the current line between times t1 and t2.

So basically the idea is to:

1. Draw a svg within a chart
2. Convert the svg path to coordinates x and y between times t1 and t2
3. Update the current list of data points with the new coordinates from the drawn shape
   4.Re-draw the graph with the new shape between times t1 and t2

I know how to draw a shape with SVG.(https://reactjsexample.com/a-hooks-to-svg-drawing/).
I know how to convert the svg path to coordinates x and y

What I don't know is whether I can use any of the reactJS library charts out there, and draw SVG on top of it ?

If the two cannot coexist together, is the only option to build my own chart within a canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up building the whole thing using d3 and reactJS